# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3}{2n^{p+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, proof-writing

Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3}{2n^{p+1}}$ . What will be the best proof for convergence of this series, which criterion will be the best?

Comment: Do you mean sequence or series?

Comment: series as i wrote in the question

Comment: You should use the summation symbol in that case.

Comment: Integral Test or Raabe's Test are both fine. And if you wanna do it in a more basic way, search for how people prove $\zeta(1)$ diverges using $S(2^n)$ and you will get enlightened in dealing with general cases like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Since the terms are positive, decreasing and approaching 0, as $n\to\infty$ you can easily test for convergence with the integral test.

Comment: I would prefere different method.

Comment: There is also the Cauchy condensation test. See here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Riemann criterion :

$\sum n^{-\alpha}$ converge if and only if $\alpha > 1$

You have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3}{2n^{p+1}} = \frac{3}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-(p+1)}$$

So here your serie converge if and only if p > 0

Answer (score 0):

another way of thinking about the Riemann criterion is setting $ -(p+1)=-a $ with the condition $ a>1 $.

From here, you will get :

$ -p-1=-a $

$ a-p=1 $

$ p=a-1 $ where $ a>0 $.

Therefore, to satisfy this equation, $ p>0 $.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy's Condensation test (i.e. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n f(2^n)$ converges):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n  * 3}{2 (2^n)^{p+1}}$$

$$ = \frac{3}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{pn}}$$

Can you take it from here?